# Way to Prevent Rusting Racks?

Tags: sous-vide, utensils

I'm using metal racks with sous-vide cooking to help keep the packets separate, and they're rusting on me. The racks are mostly chrome plated (or maybe nickle). Is there a waterproof paint or coating that I could apply to a non-rusted rack that would protect it? It would have to be a food safe coating (ie I could eat food if I were to cook on it directly), ideally oven safe, and preferably durable enough to scrub. Does something like that exist?

Comment: What's special about the racks that you couldn't replace them with something made of stainless steel? This would be a permanent solution unlike trying to coat plated steel, and would probably be cheaper in the long run

Comment: That is acceptable, it's just that I frequently see items labeled as "stainless" get reviews that talk about rusting.

Comment: Reviews talking of stainless knives or stainless pots, racks, trays rusting? The stainless steel used for knives is a very different alloy and for more prone to rusting. Besides that: brine, acids and galvanic corrosion (dissimilar metals + electrolyte) get the better of many supposedly stainless metals.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use metal racks, the solution is to acquire stainless steel racks...food safe, oven safe, washable....you probably just need 1/4 sheet pan racks, [like this.](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/choice-8-1-2-x-12-chrome-plated-footed-wire-cooling-rack-pan-grate-for-quarter-size-sheet-pan/407CRKQRTRCH.html)

Comment: I believe the type of racks OP is referring to is similar to this one https://www.amazon.com/LIPAVI-Float-preventer-Stainless-L10X/dp/B07NZV5R8H I got a similar one so I don't need to worry about bags clumping together or water getting in the ziplocks. The one in the link says "marine 316 steel" so no rust?

Comment: @Luciano could be as those came standard with one of the earlier versions of home sous vide (sous vide supreme, I believe). Almost anything will work, the idea is just to create space for circulation while helping keep the bag submerged.  I happen to use the racks I linked to because they can serve more than one purpose in my kitchen.

Comment: indeed the one you suggest are more versatile, but for sous-vide they might be too big to fit in a home cooking container. Also (at least where I live) I can't find those for cheap

Comment: @Luciano, ahh, I see.  I linked the 1/2 size.  I meant to link the 1/4 size.  That is now corrected. Still might not work for everyone, but easier to fit into smaller containers.